# What are good books and other resources to study the Cryogenics?

Tags: resource-recommendations, electronics, low-temperature-physics, cryogenics

I'm beginner in cryogenics. Also please suggest something which will be useful for study of Electronics at Cryogenic Temperatures.

Comment: Start with Cryogenic Systems by Randall Barron. If you are interested in superconductor electronics, these is a good introductory textbook by Johann Hinken.

Comment: Thank you! @nole. Yeah I want to explore about superconductivity and effect of low temperature on electronics as well.